JAX-RS FormParam compatibility break while migrating from Java8 to Java17
Recently, our project got migrated from Java8 to Java17. Which resulted in one of the regressions, the way @FormParam is handled on our API.
We did not have any @Consumes annotation in our API, and Java8 (JAX-RS) accepted the request from the clients with or without the application/x-www-form-urlencoded content-type in request header.
One of our legacy web clients (IPPhone) invokes this API with  text/xml as content-type.
Upon migration to Java17,  REST API invocation from IPPhone client broke as the server complains of the following error,
The @FormParam is utilized when the content type of the request entity is not application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Since there is no way to set request headers in request from IPPhone i.e. we can't impose addding Content-Type = application/x-www-form-urlencoded request header in request,
is there any alternate way we can fix the above regression.
I tried replacing @FormParam with  @FormDataParam. In this case, we get
415 - Unsupported Media Type  error.
One of the ways I can think of is getting request InputStream and text parsing it to get needed FormValues, but this solution looks ugly.
Any alternate way to fix this is really helpful.
Thanks,
Brinal
